# If the spread between two assets is an OU process, what processes do the two assets follow?

Tags: stochastic-processes, spread

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P}, (\mathcal{F}_{t})_{t\geq0})$ be a filtered probability space. Furthemore, let $(S_{t}^{1},S_{t}^{2})_{t\geq0}$ be two assets (adapted to filtration, etc). Define $X_{t}=S^{1}_{t}-S^{2}_{t}$. If $X_{t}$ satisfies the SDE:

$dX_{t}=\xi(\zeta-X_{t})dt+\sigma dW_{t}$
($W_{t}$ is a $\mathbb{P}$ Brownian motion)

then what process does $(S_{t}^{1},S^{2}_{t})$ follow (assuming reasonable conditions like nonnegativity)?

Comment: This is a complex question, and there is probably not a unique representation. As @Kermittfrog answer shows, one possible solution is that $S^1$ and $S^2$ follow OU processes themselves.

Comment: @Kermittfrog gave probably the answer you expected (+1) but note that your general question allows for silly examples like $\text{d}S_1=\alpha S_1\text{d}t+\sigma_1\text{d}W_1$ and $\text{d}S_2=\left(\alpha S_1-\xi(\zeta-(S_1-S_2))\right)\text{d}t+\sigma_2\text{d}W_2$. You can find infinitely many of these trivial examples unless you narrow down your a problem a little.

Comment: Good point @Kevin!

Answer (score 10):

If we allow the mean reversion speeds to be identical, we could assume OU processes for the two components:

Let

$$
\begin{align}
dx_1&=\kappa_1(\theta_1-x_1)dt+\sigma_1dW_1\\
dx_2&=\kappa_2(\theta_2-x_2)dt+\sigma_2dW_2
\end{align}
$$
with $E(dW_1dW_2)=\rho dt$. Now let $z=x_1-x_2$. Then, if $\kappa_1=\kappa_2=\kappa$,

$$
\begin{align}
dz&=dx_1-dx_2\\
&=\kappa_1(\theta_1-x_1)dt+\sigma_1dW_1-\kappa_2(\theta_2-x_2)dt-\sigma_2dW_2\\
&=\kappa(\theta_1-x_1)dt+\sigma_1dW_1-\kappa(\theta_2-x_2)dt-\sigma_2dW_2\\
&=\kappa((\theta_1-\theta_2)-(x_1-x_2))dt+\sigma_1dW_1-\sigma_2dW_2\\
&\equiv\kappa(\theta_z-z)dt+\sigma_zdW_z
\end{align}
$$

where $\theta_z=\theta_1-\theta_2$ and $\sigma_z^2=\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2-2\rho\sigma_1\sigma_2$.

Comment: Excellent response! Thank you.